If time is not fundamental would that imply creationism?
If time breaks down at the Big Bang and physics say time is not fundamental but emerges from something, does that imply there was a static state before time emerged? If this static state had a structure or contained a certain quantity of something, wouldn't that imply change, since achieving a specific amount or structure would require progression from a smaller amount? However, if this change occurred in a static state than something outside of time did it? — wouldn't that necessitate creation, as the change would have happened in a state where time does not exist? How do we make sense about the origin of the universe when time and space and existence seem to be interlinked?

"before time" is one of those phrases that seems like it ought to mean something, but we don't actually know how to mean anything by it. Garyp's answer here may be useful.

Going from a state where there isn't a thing to a state where there is that thing seems to require time. Calling it "outside of time" isn't a solution to the problem as much as it just kicks the can down the road, into a dark alley that you aren't interested in investigating. The alley is dark, therefore it's reasonable to say the can never hit the ground and just remained suspended in mid air eternally because of magic - No.

If time breaks down then wouldn't there be no time or just static?

"Time breaking down" is what happens in our modelling of reality, that is, General Relativity predicts a singularity at the Big Bang—which might be wrong. Until we have a working and accepted theory of quantum gravity, we don't have a way to address questions like yours. You might give it a try at physics.se, but I'd leave out the word 'creationism' since that's a term that denotes a pseudoscientific alternative to evolution in the ears of scientists.

@Hokon I mean if time is not infinite going backwards then wouldn't frame 1 just be static.

@gs honestly just trying to think about this like I'm running a simulation and before I run the simulation I set up parameters

We don't know if time is infinite or not going backwards. The problem is that General Relativity is not thought to be entirely reliable at the big bang, and there are competing hypotheses of quantum gravity that do and do not imply an infinitely extant past. This question really cannot be answered at this time.

For example, loop quantum gravity predicts that the big bang was preceded by a big crunch: a "cosmic bounce" is what occurred, not a big bang ex nihilo. Is loop quantum gravity right? We don't know yet.

@Hokon exactly. That's why when I see most cosmetologists agree that the universe ends in heat death for forever and ever and eternity, it logically makes me think time must have had a beginning because if it was forever it would be in cycles which most cosmetologists disagree with. And if time was forever why did the universe start off in low entropy. If it was forever it would of been dispersed a long time ago. That's why I felt philosophy was better for this question

Well your question has a philosophical bent to it, but you are trying to speculate about what General Relativity says without doing the math (or maybe you have, I wouldn't know). Most here don't know the math to General Relativity and thus are ill equipped to discuss what a singularity is in General Relativity. I think understanding what that is will help you more than asking this here.

"... like I'm running a simulation" - which already presumes a creator (but also, you are very much within time, and you setting up the simulation happens across time - note that you said "before", and you're building the simulation from material things). Some of the smartest people in the world have looked at all the evidence for the "beginning" of the universe, and at best they managed to come up with a few guesses about how that happened (none of which involve a creator, because that isn't much of an answer). I don't expect any of us would be able to do any better, without that background.

The heat death of the universe is not the end of physical reality in the way that you're proposing the start of the universe happened. Heat death means particles are too far apart to increase entropy, but the particles would still be there. And it's also just a hypothesis. Also, "something that has an end also has a beginning" is not a great inference.

"We don't have a valid complete model for that yet, and may never have one" is not an argument for creationism. That's the god of the gaps again. Never confuse ignorance with either malice, or divine will.

@NotThatGuy no I was simply arguing that if time was infinite it would either be going in cycles be the same forever or just forever changing forms and since most cosmetologists agree in heath death for eternity I was simply arguing then at one point time had a literal beginning. Or just frame 1. Because of how the universe started at low entropy. Even tho if it existed forever it would of been dispersed by now

^and that's why I arrived at this "static" state where change can occur without time but having a structure or a certain amount of something would imply something outside of time caused it because u would first have to have a small amount and progress to complete thing

AFAICT, this question boils down to a simple one: "if change only happens with time, how could change happen without time?" And then the answer is obvious: these two notions are in plain contradiction and you must reject one. Supposing (as the question does) that we don't reject the latter, then we must reject the former by adopting a broader definition of "change" that doesn't require time. For instance, if you are comfortable with the idea of a gradient's colour changing over space rather than time, then it seems you can have change without time.

@kaya3 I am thinking about time like frames in a movie or a simulation. If u was to go to frame 1 and see a structure or a certain amount of something and ur a frame 1. Before time u would logically have to think that this structure or amount of something started off as small but since this sequence would have to start from a smaller amount u would have fo conclude something outside of time put it there

"creationism" is a very loaded term. It usually refers to creation by a supernatural God, particularly as described in the first chapter of Genesis, not just any notion that the universe was created at some time.

@Barmar what can be outside of time and assemble stuff then?

@devontaylor We don't know, and maybe we can't know. But calling it God is a "god of the gaps" solution.

@Barmar what would u consider actual proof of a creator then?

@devontaylor I'm not sure such a thing can exist. I'm a physicalist, so the idea of "supernatural" is contradictory to me. Anything we can discover is by definition natural, maybe just subject to physical laws we don't understand yet. The converse of Clarke's Law: "Anything that seems to be magic is just sufficiently advanced technology."

@Barmar I agree but we try to define something under logic and what I just pointed out would defy logic. having a sequence of something in a static environment before time would logically mean a change took place. idk that might be supernatural

@devontaylor can you explain to me what "before time" means? If it's outside of time, how is there a "before"?

@microondas physics are saying time is not fundamental so I logically thought well without time you would just have a static state. almost like running a simulation you would first have to initialize

@devontaylor sure, that part I get. I just don't understand how, without time (or, in a state where time does not exist [yet]) that there could be a "before". How can there be a temporal (or time-dependent) relationship without time?

@microondas I think I explained it already in a reply above but I like to think of it like setting up parameters up in a simulation before clicking "run" because in a static state how can u have a structure or an amount of something? wouldn't u have to start from small first then build it up? this would mean there's something outside of time making stuff

@devontaylor you just said (to paraphrase) "in a static state ... wouldn't you have to start small then build it up?" Can you tell me what the word "then" means, in a state with no time? Wouldn't "do thing X then do thing Y" imply that thing Y is at a later... TIME?

@microondas If there was no time then it would be static correct? so if there was some sort of structure or an amount of something then logically you would have to start small and built it up? but how can u build up something in a static state? I concluded that something outside of time must have did it then I thought creator

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Creation is when over the passage of time moving from a state in space where something doesn't exist to a state in space where something does exist; time and space themselves are requirements of creation conceptually. So, yes, it's a bit baffling to think about how, if time is structured by the mind as Kant suggests, what it even means to have creation. Creationism with a capital C, that is theological creationism is a very appealing explanation for many. From WP:

Creationism is the religious belief that nature, and aspects such as the universe, Earth, life, and humans, originated with supernatural acts of divine creation. In its broadest sense, creationism includes a continuum of religious views, which vary in their acceptance or rejection of scientific explanations such as evolution that describe the origin and development of natural phenomena.

Certainly, it's no coincidence that Genesis in the Bible has two creation myths.  Many religions and mythologies have both similar and wildly divergent stories. The Greeks had Chaos and Gaia, and Native American religions sometimes appeal to a God that plants corn allowing the universe to spring into place. We certainly are psychologically driven to explain what caused the universe.
But such explanations may rely on the assumption of the Principle of Sufficient Reason. From WP:

he principle of sufficient reason states that everything must have a reason or a cause. The principle was articulated and made prominent by Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz, with many antecedents, and was further used and developed by Arthur Schopenhauer and William Hamilton.

Science admits no knowledge can be had of the event since good science requires empirical evidence and the question seems to exclude the possibility of such evidence. Theologians often simply place faith in the belief of Biblical creation. And contemporary, professional philosophers often just dismiss the question as pointless metaphysical speculation like that conducted by the Scholastics when debating angels, dancing, and pins. One response to your question is that there are simply limits to what human being can know, and knowledge of the origins of the universe just isn't possible.

Your ignoring my actual points. if time is not fundamental or it emerges from something then I deduced that it might have came from a static state. but in this static state if there's an amount of something or a structure of some kind then in order to have that u would have to start off small logically and work your way up but how would this change occur if there's no time and were in a static state? then logically something outside of time made it

I'm not ignoring it. Your post was very unclear, and I thought about piling on with the close vote myself, but there's a good question in there somewhere. " then logically something outside of time made it" Logically, there cannot be something outside the universe, because the universe includes all space AND has no boundaries. Thus, logically, it's a meaningless question to say what happened before time in the space outside the universe. To save you some thinking, it might be helpful for you to realize that you engaged in thinking about concepts which means something like working with words..

And one of the brain works is to think of things as containers; and all you are doing is thinking at a deep level, that if the universe formed and time started, there must be a container where there is no time. And since there is a container with no time where a container with time was created, there must be an act of creation. And acts of creation suggest a creator. So, that's not absurd to think at all. It's been the default position for many thinkers for probably since myth was born before the start of civilization. Why Immanuel Kant is famous is that he claims that space and time...

are structured by the brain and then the mind... and that neither time nor space is true of the universe. It's only true of how we think about the universe, and any questions about the time and space of the universe itself are a bit misleading. Philosophers who agree with that, roughly speaking, are called instrumentalists.

"Rejecting scientific realism's ambitions to uncover metaphysical truth about nature, instrumentalism is usually categorized as an antirealism, although its mere lack of commitment to scientific theory's realism can be termed nonrealism. Instrumentalism merely bypasses debate concerning whether, for example, a particle spoken about in particle physics is a discrete entity enjoying individual existence, or is an excitation mode of a region of a field, or is something else altogether. Instrumentalism holds that theoretical terms need only be useful to predict the phenomena, the... outcomes..."

So if we start at "frame 1" and we already have an amount of something, or a structure logically wouldn't that mean u would have to start small then work your way up? that's why I'm saying something outside of time

How can you START when there is no time?

Time cannot start logically, because that presupposes time exists for time to begin.

would having an amount of something of a structure of something at "frame 1" directly imply progress? this is what im trying to Grable with. because without time it is just a static state yes?

As a scientist, I don't know what happens in a place without time. I've never seen it. It's speculation. And my speculation is that it's a meaningless question. That time and space are always together and that there is no beginning of the universe... that it just goes on and on forever. But that's just a guess. Other people like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation

Just because you can put words together doesn't mean they mean anything.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously

how would a progress happen if at "frame 1"? I feel like you're not engaging with the logic im trying to get at

That's right. Because I've explained there isn't a logic underlying, it really. 'Progress' presupposes time, so I refuse to grant there is frame1 to begin with. Time and space only happen together. I'm pushing back on your presumption. I'm not doing it to be a jerk. I'm doing it because you keep using time words in a state you say happens BEFORE time. So, I'm trying to argue your logic is inherently flawed. Let's end it here, and you think about whether you can come up with a word other than 'progress', 'start' or 'end' that doesn't presuppose time. You cannot do it is my claim.

And if you disagree, say, that you don't think that progress presupposes time, you can ask a question about it on this site and get some perspectives. Ciao!

your right. but time does happen in frames right? wouldn't u have to start at frame 1? also why do physics say time is not fundamental? that's why I thought of time starting off at a static state but how would a static state have something that would need progression to get to
